# How to make a list cycle with python

Tags: python

I have a list and I want the list to display an image whenever a certain string in the list is chosen. However, I don't know how to make it so that if you reach the end of the list, you go to the beginning again, or if you go to the beginning of the list and go backwards, you end up and the end of the list. Is there a piece code to do this?

Comment: Give it a try first, then if you're still having trouble, come back here.

Comment: Use the modulus operator, although it is easy enough to just use a couple of `if` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there are two parts to the problem.

1. you want to associate an image to an item in the list. And you don't have any issue with this.
2. you want to cycle the list, that is, once you reach the end, you wanna start over.

For cycling the list, the simplest is to use a while True loop and at the end of the loop when the last element of the list is reached, reset to the first (or zeroth) in the list.

The simplest example could be as below:

```
a = [0,1,2,3,4]
index = len(a)

while True:
    if index < len(a):
    else:
        index = 0
    print(a[index])
    index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator `%`.

```py
my_list = ["Apple", "Bannana", "Orange"]
def looping_list(my_list, index):
    return my_list[index % len(my_list)]
print(looping_list(my_list, 3)) # outputs "Apple"
```

Also can handle negative numbers just fine.